# Establecer URLs para los artículos sin crear un archivo para cada uno

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirección

Como ya saben, casi cualquier web (incluido esta misma), **no crean un archivo** con el contenido de cada artículo/post/página, sino que la página **lee la URL** y busca el artículo que debe mostrar, por ejemplo en una **base de datos**, y tomando como base una plantilla, escribe los datos.

**Ejemplo**: `https://twitter.com/stackoverflow`

*Todos sabemos que Twitter no tiene un archivo por usuario.*

Pues eso mismo quiero hacer. Estoy haciendo mi propio sistema de blog, y quiero saber cómo puedo acceder al artículo X usando `ejemplo.com/articulo-de-ejemplo`.

Tan solo quiero saber qué sistema debo usar, no el proceso de añadir la url y el contenido a la base de datos, ya que eso ya lo tengo, pero en estos momentos solo puedo hacerlo usando `ejemplo.com/p?=articulo-de-ejemplo`.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución.

Hay que usar el archivo **.htaccess** y añadir en él las siguientes líneas:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?id=$1
```

Entonces, lo que hará el archivo es redirigir (**sin cambiar el contenido de la URL**) todas las peticiones que realmente "**no tengan resultados**" al archivo indicado anteriormente.

En el caso del ejemplo, estoy redirigiendo al archivo **index.php**, que al tener la "`/`" al principio, indico que está en la ruta principal.

Se puede modificar el `/index.php` por `/articulos/plantilla.php` o por cualquier otra ruta.

Otra cosa más es el ?id=$1, que permite enviarle al documento al que redirigimos la url con la que hemos accedido, es decir, si escribo:

```
ejemplo.com/articulo-de-ejemplo
```

El htacces nos va a abrir el archivo `index.php` y le va a pasar a este el parámetro `id` con el valor `articulo-de-ejemplo`, que podrá ser usado para buscar el artículo en la base de datos.